# Are there any examples of married, male, non-martyred (white crown), non-royal, canonized Catholic Saints excluding Saint Joseph?

Tags: catholicism, saint

Are there any examples of married, male, non-martyred (white crown), non-royal, canonized Catholic Saints excluding Saint Joseph? I can't think of a single one!

The question may seem to impose arbitrary qualifications but for good reason. As someone who fits in to all those categories (assuming I am not martyred) - I am looking for saints to imitate who had (relatively) relatable circumstances in their life and still achieved a high enough level of holiness as to be acknowledged by the Catholic church as a canonized saint.

It seems every saint I read about either died a martyr, was a priest, died as a child, or was a woman who was sanctified through dealing with her husband haha, or was of royal/imperial status such as Constantine.

Comment: This site lists 10 married couples who were both saints, 1 of which is Mary and Joseph. https://www.churchpop.com/2017/07/07/10-holy-married-couples-who-were-both-saints/

Comment: It should be noted that we do not know the marital disposition of many of the apostles, and since John the Apostle is not believed to have been martyred it is possible that he would qualify.

Comment: The first who comes to mind is Saint Louis Martin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The book *Married Saints and Blesseds: Through the Centuries* by Ferdinand Holböck is a good source to look for married saints to imitate. Here are a few saints from that book which (seem to) meet your criteria:

- [St. Joachim (father of Mary)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim)
- [St. Zechariah (father of John the Baptist)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zechariah_(New_Testament_figure))
- [St. Basil the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basil_the_Elder)
- [St. Gregory of Nazianzus the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_of_Nazianzus_the_Elder)
- [St. Hilary of Poiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_of_Poitiers)
- [St. Paulinus of Nola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paulinus_of_Nola)
- [St. Bernard of Vienne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_of_Vienne)
- [St. Raymond Zanfogni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_the_Palmer)
- [St. Giovanni Colombini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Colombini)
- [St. Alphonsus Rodriguez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonsus_Rodriguez)
- [St. Louis Martin (father of St. Thérèse of Lisieux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Martin_and_Marie-Az%C3%A9lie_Gu%C3%A9rin)

Answer (score 3):

Selden Peabody Delany's [*Married Saints*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7416) contains biographies of these:

1. Saint Monica [331-387]
2. Saint Paulinus of Nola [353-431]
3. Saint Margaret of Scotland [1045-1083]
4. Saint Elizabeth of Hungary [1207-1231]
5. Saint Louis of France [1214-1270]
6. Saint Frances of Rome [1384-1440]
7. Blessed Nicholas of Flue [1417-1487]
8. Saint Thomas More [1478-1535]
9. Madame Acarie [1566-1618]
10. Blessed Anna Maria Taigi [1769-1837]
11. Mother Elizabeth Seton [1774-1821]
12. The Married Life of Cornelia Connelly [1809-1879]
13. Louis Veuillot [1813-1883]
14. Frederic Ozanam [1813-1853]
15. Elizabeth Arrighi Leseur [1866-1914]
16. Lucie Felix-Faure Goyau [1866-1913]
17. Three Apostles of Catholic Action

    1. Giambattista Paganuzzi [1830-1910]
    2. Giuseppe Toniolo [1845-1918]
    3. Ludovico Necchi [1876-1930]

Comment: +1 you've mixed females in there.

Comment: St. Louis is also a king

Comment: Thomas More was martyred.

Comment: #7 *Saint* Nicholas of Flue, patron saint of Switzerland, was formally canonized in 1947. The son of peasants, he married and had ten children with his wife. A farmer, military leader, council member, and judge, in 1467 (at the age of fifty), he became a hermit, with the consent of his wife and family.

Comment: Yes, I've included more than the questioner asked.